# PYTEST - How to make CONFTEST.PY available in other python directories

Tags: python, automation, pytest

Currently my test cases and `conftest.py` are under a `testsuites` directory.
I have utility Python files under a `config` directory i.e. `config/databaseconnection.py`

I am trying to read properties related to a DB connection using a function defined in `conftest.py` and marked with `pytest.fixture`.

Looks like `conftest.py` is not available outside the `testsuites` directory.

How do I make `conftest.py` available in other directories/packages?

Any code sample to make DB Connection string available at `session` level using `conftest.py` would be appriciated.

Comment: You can import from `conftest.py` if you turn your `testsuites` directory into a package by adding a `__init__.py` file. This will allow you to import the fixture, but will still show errors when you call it: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly

Comment: Don't import from `conftest`s even in tests, it's a bad idea. `conftest`s should be treated only as local extensions for `pytest`. Moreover, you shouldn't use any test code in production code. Is `config/databaseconnection.py` a utility used in tests only? Why not put it under `testsuites`? Can you provide a [mcve]?